# many users edit question at the same time

Tags: support, edits

I am facing the following problem sometimes I hit edit button and at the same times someone else is editing the question for example: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/130025/install-sql-server-2000-on-windows-10 is there a way to gray it out when someone edit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be the same request as:

[Lock a post for editing, or at least display a warning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141252/lock-a-post-for-editing-or-at-least-display-a-warning) on Meta.SE

I agree this is annoying, and have no idea why it hasn't been progressed.

P.S. Apologies for rejecting your concurrent suggested tag edit there. Approving it would have overwritten my own, much more substantial edit.

Comment: Thanks Paul, your edit it much better than mine. I agree with your decision to reject the edit.